# MT4 calculations issue

Tags: statistics, metatrader4

In Mt4 you can generate a [**Detailed Report**] in Terminal by going to Account History->right click->generate detailed report

Is it possible to do it not by client terminal?

Comment: do you have a question or are you just looking for ppl to show how to do it? I don't think you'll get much love here just asking for code samples

Answer (score -2):

You need to first backtest your strategy then you san save the detailed report.

Comment: Because the [Detailed Report] can be generated for real trading records about trades that were executed on a Server ( not on a localhost only emulation ) at live Market prices ( be it on a Real Account, or just on a Demo Account ). And also this was the context in which it was asked in the original post.